# formula vs well-formed formula in propositional logic

Tags: logic, formula, formal-languages, well-formed

Can someone please explain the difference between *formula in general* and *well-formed formula*? 
Is it possible to determine the truth value of an ill-formed formula?

Comment: Thanks for asking that question ;) - 14.2 guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validity of a formula, or its truth value (or more generally its evaluation), can only be assessed if the formula is well formed with respect to a given set of syntax rules.

So a formula **in general**, and in the context of math or logic, means *well-formed* formula.

Strictly speaking, you can say that if your symbols include  `'+' | '(' | ')' | 'a'-'z'`, a formula, in the strict sense, is any string formed by these symbols. For example, `a((++z` is a formula.

But one must also look at the rules of construction of a formula. And if the rules are, for example

```
F,E ::= F + E | (F) | 'a'-'z'
```

then your formula is not well formed.

Comment: ZakC is correct, but just to emphasise the point: there is almost no situation in logic when "formula" does not mean "well-formed formula". And in direct answer to the OP's second question: an ill-formed formula has no truth value.

Comment: Thank you @ZakC for your explaination